# Determine count of object retrieval per day in django

Tags: django

In a model like the one below

```
class Watched(Stamping):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Anytime an object is retrieved, I increment the **count** attribute.
Now my problem is how to get the number of times an object was retrieved for each day of the week
For example, **WatchedObject1** will have `{'Sun': 10, 'Tue': 70, 'Wed': 35}`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a use case for auditing and there are plugins for Django that can help you with that. If you don't want to add this dependency you would have to create another model that you store your intended data.

```
class RetrievalOfData(models.Model):
      date_of_retrieval = models.datetimefield(auto_now_add=True)
      object_retrieved = models.ForeignKey("Watched")
```

You could probably also override the manager to create these objects everytime the model is queried: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/

Answer (score 0):

You might find it better to have a separate `WatchedModelStats` table, and perhaps link it you your model with Django signals. Whenever a countable event takes place, execute something like

```
try:
    counter = WatchedModelStats.objects.get( name=model_name, date=today)
    counter.count += 1
except WatchedModelStats.DoesNotExist:
    counter = WatchedModelStats( name=model_name, date=today, count=1 ) 

counter.save()
```

One advantage is extensibility. You could easily implement multiple counts for differerent event types, if the need later becomes apparent.

Comment: What changes will I make in the models file

Comment: None? I'm suggesting adding a new model to store counts, per-day. Obviously, whatever you are doing to detect when your model is "accessed" (updated?) needs to execute the code I suggest. One way would be to use a Django post-save signal to connect them, rather than hardcoding.